# Align two divs horizontally (one on extreme left and the other on extreme right of container)

Tags: html, css, alignment, frontend, display

I'm working on a game website and want to place two divs inside a 'header' div such that they are horizontally aligned and to the left and right of this container div. See below for an example:

```
Oli                                                                             Matt
```

Here is my attempt. What is my error?

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
     <div class="playerOne">
     Oli
     </div>
     <div class="playerTwo">
     Matt
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header{
  display: inline-block;
}
.playerOne{
    margin-left: 0;
 }

.playerTwo{
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- `display:inline-block` will not create a `float` issue so there is no need to add clearfix
- you can also use `overflow:hidden` instead of `display:inline-block`

```css
.header {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.playerOne {
  float: right;
}
.playerTwo {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="playerOne">
    Oli
  </div>
  <div class="playerTwo">
    Matt
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: make div display as inline-block works.

Answer (score 18):

make it simple with flex

`.wrapper{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between
}`

`<div class="wrapper"><span>1</span><span>2</span></div>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x17skhap/

Comment: Such a perfect solution. I was struggling to get it done and this solution worked!

Comment: Simple and great

Comment: Such simple and elegant solution. Thanks Thiru!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are not targeting the proper inline-block element. :)

```
.header > div{
  display: inline-block;
}
.playerOne{
  float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using floats?

```
.playerOne{
    float: left
 }

.playerTwo{
  float: right
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfLa5nmL/